# Closing with same character, other replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a live preview, where I have to replace some characters. When I type `*text*`, it should replace it with the html: `<span class="txt-bold">text</span>`.

The first part of my code seems to be successful, but I don't know how to modify the REGEX so that it's correctly replacing the second asterisk with the closing tag for SPAN.

This may sound really stupid, but on my research here I couldn't really find a solution.

```
textarea_content = textarea_content.replace(/\*/g, '<span class="txt-bold">').replace(/\[\/*\]/g, '</span>');
```

Comment: Note that nothing about this is anything to do with jQuery. I've changed the title and re-tagged the question acordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the first Regex will replace all `*` instances with the opening `<span>` tag, so the second `replace()` call won't match anything.

A better solution would be to use a single Regex to match a group and then do the replacement with that. Try this:

```js
var foo = 'some dummy *text*';
var bar = foo.replace(/\*(.+)\*/g, '<span class="txt-bold">$1</span>');

console.log(bar);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a way better solution. Thanks. This indeed did fix the problem.